# Методы loadView, viewDidLoad и viewWillAppear

Tags: cocoa, objective-c, ios

В каких случаях могут не вызываться эти методы при добавлении компоненты?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

loadView, viewDidLoad могут не вызываться у компонент, созданных из xib, viewWillAppear к этому отношения не имеет